# Gradle tells me ' Must specify a repository for deployment'

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I tried write a gradle plugin,and i want deploy it to localMaven.
I write code like this

```
group='cn.sola.gradle'
version='1.0-SNAPSHOT'
uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        mavenLocal()
     }
   }
}
```

Then I run this command **gradle -q upload**
But gradle print like this:

```
* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
  > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
    > Must specify a repository for deployment
enter code here
```

But my file is already there.
The files under the directory is like this.

```
ls ~/.m2/repository/cn/sola/gradle/HelloGradlePlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/

HelloGradlePlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar       ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
HelloGradlePlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.sha1  ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml.sha1
```

What does the exception mean?And is the file OK?

----add information----

```
:uploadArchives (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:uploadArchives
Executing task ':uploadArchives' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Publishing configuration: configuration ':archives'
Publishing to Maven repository 'MavenLocal'
Published HelloGradlePlugin.jar (cn.sola.gradle:HelloGradlePlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT) to file:/Users/sola1tmy/.m2/repository/cn/sola/gradle/HelloGradlePlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloGradlePlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Published ivy.xml (cn.sola.gradle:HelloGradlePlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT) to file:/Users/sola1tmy/.m2/repository/cn/sola/gradle/HelloGradlePlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
Publishing to org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer@b46e103
:uploadArchives FAILED
:uploadArchives (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.516 secs.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "deploy" your jar (or whatever) to the local maven repository there is a `install` task provided by the maven plugin. The only thing you must do is calling:

```
gradle install
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#uploading_to_maven_repositories (look at 32.6.3)